# Job condition with global variable

Tags: autosys

I need to schedule a job. I want it to run if, and only if some global variable (let's say RUNNING_ID) is not equal to 0.

Is that possible ?

If it is, waht is the Condition syntax for the job description ?

I tried RUNNING_ID!=0, and got this error :

`CAUAJM_E_10037 CONDITION ERROR: Illegal Key Word: RUNNING_ID!=0
CAUAJM_E_10281 ERROR for Job: CVAT-TENSEN2CUX-launch_decision < Error in Starting Conditions. >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out :

The syntax :
VALUE(global_variable_name) operator value

with operator being one of these : =, !=, <, >, <= and >=